# Iterating over NavItems component with javascript or angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a navbar component with an app sidebar with navItems attribute on my angular project.

here is how my navBar content is :

```
<app-header style="background-color : #e65100;"
  [fixed]="true"
  [navbarBrandFull]="{ src: 'assets/img/brand/Bouygues_Construction_logo.svg', width: 350, height: 50, alt: 'AAD' }"
  [navbarBrandMinimized]="{ src: 'assets/img/brand/sygnet.svg', width: 30, height: 30, alt: 'AAD' }"
  [sidebarToggler]="'lg'"
  [asideMenuToggler]="'lgX'"
>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto" >
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" dropdown placement="bottom right" >
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        href="#"
        role="button"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false"
        dropdownToggle
        (click)="(false)"
      >
        <span class="d-md-down-none" style="color: white; font-style: bold;">{{ currentUser.firstName }} {{ currentUser.lastName }}</span>
        <img
          src="http://argosstockage.bouygues-construction.com/ArgosStockage/images/photos/PERSONNE____________{{
            currentUser.idArgos
          }}.jpg"
          (error)="getDefaultImage($event)"
          class="img-avatar"
          alt="{{ currentUser.lastName }}"
        />
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" *dropdownMenu aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> Paramètres</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" (click)="logOut()"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Se déconnecter</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</app-header>
<div class="app-body">
  <app-sidebar [fixed]="true" [display]="'lg'"  style="background-color : #e65100;">
    <ng-scrollbar>
      <app-sidebar-nav  [navItems]="navItems"></app-sidebar-nav>
    </ng-scrollbar>
    <app-sidebar-minimizer></app-sidebar-minimizer>
  </app-sidebar>
  <!-- Main content -->
  <main class="main">
    <!-- Breadcrumb -->
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
    </ol>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </main>
</div>
<app-footer>
  <span><b>AAD</b> &copy; 2022 Bouygues Construction IT.</span>
  <span class="ml-auto"> <a href="#">Bouygues Construction IT</a></span>
</app-footer>
```

and here is how my navItems value is composed

```
export const navItems = [
  {
    name: 'Tableau de bord',
    url: '/dashboard',
    icon: 'icon-speedometer',
  },
  {
    title: true,
    name: 'Projets BBI',
  },
  {
    name: 'Projects',
    url: '/projects',
    icon: 'icon-speedometer',
  },
  {
    name: 'Selections',
    url: '/selections',
    icon: 'icon-envelope',
  },
  {
    name: 'Commercial Launching',
    url: '/commercial-launching',
    icon: 'icon-exclamation',
  },
  {
    title: true,
    name: 'Gestion Admin',
  },
  {
    name: 'Users',
    url: '/users',
    icon: 'icon-user',
  },
  {
    name: 'Applications',
    url: '/applications',
    icon: 'icon-screen-smartphone',
  },
  {
    name: 'Currencies',
    url: '/currencies',
    icon: 'icon-bills',
  },
  {
    name: 'Countries',
    url: '/countries',
    icon: 'icon-globe',
  },
  {
    name: 'Internal Clients',
    url: '/internalClients',
    icon: 'icon-wallet',
  },
  {
    name: 'Business Lines',
    url: '/businesslines',
    icon: 'icon-screen-desktop',
  },
  {
    name: 'Products',
    url: '/products',
    icon: 'icon-tag',
  },
  {
    name: 'Languages',
    url: '/languages',
    icon: 'icon-pencil',
  },
  {
    name: 'Roles',
    url: '/roles',
    icon: 'icon-eye',
  },
  {
    name: 'Tenders',
    url: '/tenders',
    icon: 'icon-briefcase',
  },
  {
    name: 'Unity Significative',
    url: '/unitySignificatives',
    icon: 'icon-star',
  },
  {
    title: true,
    name: 'Administration',
  },
  {
    name: 'Configuration',
    url: '/base',
    icon: 'icon-settings',
  },
  {
    name: 'Droits',
    url: '/buttons',
    icon: 'icon-shield',
  },
];
```

So i would like to iterate over each item of my navItems and to add for each item an attribute hidden with the value 'false',

i've tried to make it like that for now:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { navItems } from '@app/_nav';
import { AuthenticationService } from '@app/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './default-layout.component.html',
})
export class DefaultLayoutComponent {
  public navItems = navItems;
  private changes: MutationObserver;
  counter = 0;
  //public showDatas = false;
  public element: HTMLElement = document.body;

  public currentUser: any;

  

  constructor(private router: Router, private _authService: AuthenticationService) {
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUser = this._authService.getCurrentUser();
    
  }

  public getDefaultImage($event) {
    if (this.currentUser) {
      /* for(const anItem in navItems) {
        console.log("****************************"+navItems[anItem].name);
        if(navItems[anItem].name=="Administration") {
          anItem['hidden'] = false
        }
      } */

      /* navItems.forEach(element => {
        element.hidden = true;
        console.log("*****************"+element);
      });
      
      navItems.map(function(entry) {
        entry.hidden = true;
        return entry;
    })
    }
    console.log(navItems);


    for(const anItem of navItems) {
      anItem['hidden'] = true;
      console.log(anItem);
    }
    console.log(navItems); */
    
    $event.target.src = `https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=${this.currentUser.firstName}+${this.currentUser.lastName}`;
    
    
    }
    /* for(const anItem of navItems) {
      anItem['hidden'] = true;
      console.log(anItem);
      navItems[this.counter] = anItem;
      this.counter = this.counter + 1;
    } */


      /* for(const anItem of navItems) {
        anItem['hidden'] = false
      }
      this.navItems = [...navItems]; */
  }

  public hideNav($event) {
    for(const anItem of navItems) {
      anItem['hidden'] = true;
      console.log(anItem)
    }
    this.navItems = [...navItems];

}
  

  /* public hideNav($event) {
    for(const anItem of navItems) {
      anItem['hidden'] = true;
      console.log(anItem);
    }

} */

  /* public hideNav($event) {
    for(const anItem of navItems) {
      anItem['hidden'] = true;
    }
} */

  public showGestionAdmin($event) {
    if(this.currentUser) {

      for(const anItem in navItems) {
        console.log("****************************"+anItem);
      }

    }
  }

  public logOut() {
    this._authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

when i try to change the current Item, i don't know how to add an attribute to the current item

My idea is then to pass in parameters the role of the current user and if it is equal to "admin", the management part of the navBar would be hidden from the user.

here is how the appsidebarComponent is imported :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B72Qi.png)

```
import * as i0 from "@angular/core";
import * as i1 from "./app-sidebar-footer.component";
import * as i2 from "./app-sidebar-form.component";
import * as i3 from "./app-sidebar-header.component";
import * as i4 from "./app-sidebar-minimizer.component";
import * as i5 from "./app-sidebar.component";
import * as i6 from "./app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav-items.component";
import * as i7 from "./app-sidebar-nav.component";
import * as i8 from "./app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav-divider.component";
import * as i9 from "./app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav-link.component";
import * as i10 from "./app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav-title.component";
import * as i11 from "./app-sidebar-nav.directive";
import * as i12 from "./app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav-label.component";
import * as i13 from "./app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav-icon.pipe";
import * as i14 from "./app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav-badge.pipe";
import * as i15 from "./app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav-link.pipe";
import * as i16 from "./app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav-item-class.pipe";
import * as i17 from "@angular/common";
import * as i18 from "@angular/router";
import * as i19 from "../shared/layout/layout.module";
export declare class AppSidebarModule {
    static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AppSidebarModule, never>;
    static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<AppSidebarModule, [typeof i1.AppSidebarFooterComponent, typeof i2.AppSidebarFormComponent, typeof i3.AppSidebarHeaderComponent, typeof i4.AppSidebarMinimizerComponent, typeof i4.AppSidebarMinimizerComponent, typeof i5.AppSidebarComponent, typeof i6.AppSidebarNavItemsComponent, typeof i7.AppSidebarNavComponent, typeof i8.AppSidebarNavDividerComponent, typeof i6.AppSidebarNavDropdownComponent, typeof i9.AppSidebarNavLinkComponent, typeof i9.AppSidebarNavLinkContentComponent, typeof i10.AppSidebarNavTitleComponent, typeof i11.NavDropdownDirective, typeof i11.NavDropdownToggleDirective, typeof i12.AppSidebarNavLabelComponent, typeof i13.AppSidebarNavIconPipe, typeof i14.AppSidebarNavBadgePipe, typeof i15.AppSidebarNavLinkPipe, typeof i16.AppSidebarNavItemClassPipe], [typeof i17.CommonModule, typeof i18.RouterModule, typeof i19.LayoutModule], [typeof i1.AppSidebarFooterComponent, typeof i2.AppSidebarFormComponent, typeof i3.AppSidebarHeaderComponent, typeof i4.AppSidebarMinimizerComponent, typeof i5.AppSidebarComponent, typeof i7.AppSidebarNavComponent]>;
    static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<AppSidebarModule>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for of loop and string literal to add the hidden property for each item

```js
public hideNav($event) {
    for(const anItem of this.navItems) {
      anItem['attributes']= { hidden: true },
    }
    this.navItems = [...this.navItems]

}
```

P.S. you should add a default hidden value even if it is null so that you can use the dot operator anItem.hidden instead of anItem['hidden']

Comment: i've add a default hidden value even null or equals to true, that's working but the visibility do not change ^^

Comment: if you mean the items in the app-sidebar-nav component are not hidden then you need to force change detection to run, I have updated the answer.

Comment: i see but i did not understand what means this line :
    navItems = [...navItems]


 if you can clarify it to me please i'm a losed a little, sorry...

Comment: if you are binding an array to the child element, and you want to update the template of the child element by modifying the contents for that array you need to force Angular to detect that change, one of the ways to do this is by creating a new array and assign it to navItems, that is what  navItems = [...navItems] is doing

Comment: ok i see, but when i try this, that error message comes to me : 

Cannot assign to 'navItems' because it is an import.

Comment: i've add this.navItems :

`public hideNav($event) {
    for(const anItem of navItems) {
      anItem['hidden'] = true;
      console.log(anItem)
    }
    this.navItems = [...navItems];

}
`
, it seems working but there is the same result, the value are set in my console but

Comment: can you add the full ts code to the question, it will be easier to debug

Comment: ok, i'll do it, but i tried also to just set manually hidden: false and it won't take effect at all, i suspect if maybe the thing that the problem is the attribute himself who's not working at well...

Comment: use this.navItems instead of navItems inside hideNav method, if it still does not work then the issue could be inside app-sidebar-nav component

Comment: I've added the whole component.html if it can help you to find out the problem... Thank you again to help me...

Comment: I think the problem is in the app-sidebar-nav template, can you add the app-sidebar-nav html, specially the part where the hidden property is used

Comment: the appsidebarcomponent comes from an import, i've added picture to illustrate how it is imported

Comment: i've placed the hidden fonction  like this :  

`<app-sidebar-nav  [navItems]="navItems" (click)="hideNav($event)"></app-sidebar-nav>`

i've delete this click event 'cause it does the same problem...

Comment: you are using Core UI?, I have updated the answer

Comment: yes i use core UI, is it different in some way ? cause i'm using a template based on the web project working  of my company?

When i replace the function, i have this error message : 

a property 'attributes' does not exist on type '{ name: string; url: string; icon: string; hidden: boolean; title?: undefined; } | { title: boolean; name: string; hidden: boolean; url?: undefined; icon?: undefined; } | { name: string; url: string; icon: string; hidden?: undefined; title?: undefined; }'.

Comment: no I was thinking it is a custom component, try anItem['attributes']= { hidden: true },

Comment: i've added the solution to the issue in an other comment, thank you a lot !!!!!!

Comment: my bad , the function hideNav's not working, but the static attributes works well

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

```
navItems.map(function(entry) {
    entry.hidden = false;
    return entry;
});
```

Sample:

```js
const navItems = [
  {
    name: 'Tableau de bord',
    url: '/dashboard',
    icon: 'icon-speedometer',
  },
  {
    title: true,
    name: 'Projets BBI',
  },
  {
    name: 'Projects',
    url: '/projects',
    icon: 'icon-speedometer',
  }      
];

navItems.map(function(entry) {
    entry.hidden = false;
    return entry;
});

console.log(navItems)
```

Comment: i've tried this but it comes that error message unfortunately :



Property 'hidden' does not exist on type '{ name: string; url: string; icon: string; title?: undefined; } | { title: boolean; name: string; url?: undefined; icon?: undefined; }'.
  Property 'hidden' does not exist on type '{ name: string; url: string; icon: string; title?: undefined; }'.

Comment: plus i'm a little confused, i don't know what does mean the "entry" variable if you can clear to me it please ^^...

Comment: i've tried it, when i've add hidden attributes manually it works but the navItem elements stay visible ...

Answer (score -1):

I've found out the problem, we have just to change navItems hidden attribute

i was writting it like this :

`{ title: true, name: 'Administration', hidden: false },`

the good syntax :

`{ title: true, name: 'Administration', attributes: { hidden: false } },`

So as we can see, i have juste replaced `hidden : false` by

`attributes: { hidden: false }` but the "hideNav()" function doesn't work well